# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present when using Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, cors

I am trying to oauth to twitter using ***angular*** -> ***node*** -> ***twitter*** but i keep getting the error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access` when adding angular to the mix. My app configuration..

- Angular UI running on port 4200
- Express Node Server running on port 3000
- CORS on server is set to Allow-Access-Origin localhost:4200 for Angular to Node
  api calls.

Using express templates that call call express routes works fine as shown below

**template  -> localhost:3000/auth/twitter**

```
Response Headers
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
    Location:https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=placeholdertokenstackoverflow
    Vary:Origin

Request Headers
    Host:localhost:3000
    Referer:http://localhost:3000/
```

**localhost:3000/auth/twitter -> //api.twitter.com/oauth/...**

```
GENERAL
    Request URL:https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=placeholdertokenstackoverflow
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 

Request Headers
    :authority:api.twitter.com
    :method:GET
    :scheme:https
    referer:http://localhost:3000/
```

When using angular to call express routes instead of templates, causes what i assume is a CORS error as shown below

**angular.http.get -> localhost:3000/auth/twitter**

```
RESPONSE HEADERS
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
    Location:https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=placeholdertokenstackoverflow
    Vary:Origin

REQUEST HEADERS
    Host:localhost:3000
    Origin:http://localhost:4200
    Referer:http://localhost:4200/
```

**localhost:3000/auth/twitter -> //api.twitter.com/oauth/...**

```
GENERAL
    Request URL:https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=placeholdertokenstackoverflow
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:200 

REQUEST HEADERS
    :authority:api.twitter.com
    :method:GET
    :scheme:https
    ***origin:null
    referer:http://localhost:4200/***
```

Looking above `origin:null` appears when angular calls the express route. Even though express server is set up the same in both instances and makes the call to twitter, the headers are different which i dont understand. Does angular setting the view instead of express make the browser confused on the origin of the request?

Comment: hmm. Is your angular on a different server than your express server? Typically using express as a middleman is done with the purpose of avoiding CORS all together. Why is the location of your request the twitter api, if you're making the request to express? What does express have to do with this? From what I'm seeing sitting here, you're not actually using express with this request. something looks very off.

Comment: angular makes the call to express server which configures the settings needed to authenticate to twitter. then express calls to authenticate twitter, gets the token and relays it all back to the browser via angular

Comment: Ok, start with this. eliminate twitter api from your testing. Are you able to communicate with your express server that way?

Comment: Also... Why are you using a middleman server for OAuth? you shouldn't have to.

Comment: twitter requires credentials that i cant expose to the browser like my application token and secret . and yes this is part of a larger application that works fine with express server.

Comment: the origin null for example is likely because your express request isn't setting an origin.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the node server to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to enable cross-origin requests from anywhere (or specify a domain instead of *). This should solve your problem.
Here is how I solved my issue:

```
const app = express()
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express, you can try this [cors package](https://github.com/expressjs/cors).

EDIT:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/products/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: please include a solution in your post. don't just link to one.